# Showing that $\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} (a_1 z+ a_2 z^2+...) = \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to show that $$\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} |(a_1 z+ a_2 z^2+...)| = \infty$$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$. I am not entirely sure the result is true, but it seems like it should be. I know that $z\rightarrow \infty$ means that $|z|\rightarrow \infty$. So I tried the following:

$$\infty =\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} |z|\cdot\bigg||a_1|-|a_2||z|-|a_3||z|^3-...\bigg|\leq\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} |z|\cdot|a_1+a_2z+a_3z^2+...|$$

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: I think you should have meant to take the modulus (absolute value) of that expression, which I am guessing is a polynomial, otherwise that could be undefined at all...

Comment: Yes I was meaning to take the modulus, I will edit it now. In that case, will my attempt make sense?

Comment: @Dצשמ You must make clear what that expression $\;a_1z+a_2z^2\ldots\;$ is.

Comment: It is an infinite polynomial

Comment: "It is an infinite polynomial" There is no such thing as "an infinite polynomial".

Comment: @Dman You should really think of this a little deeper. If you do complex analysis is because, I guess, you already did real analysis, linear algebra and some other basic courses. You should know there is no such thing as "infinite polynomial". What exist are *power series*, for example...but this dudes are usually restricted to some set of possible values for $\;z\;$ which won't usually allow you to do $\;|z|\to\infty\;$ ...

Comment: If $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z^k$ has infinite radius of convergence then it is true that $$\lim_{r \to \infty} \max_{|z| = r} \left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z^k\right| = \infty.$$

Comment: @AntonioVargas Not really, as constant functions like $\;f(z)=1\;$ don't fulfill that ...

Comment: @DonAntonio, right, I forgot the requirement that the series is not a polynomial. If there are infinitely many terms then it's true.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Yes...in fact, any non-constant analytic function will do, because of Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If $P(z)=a_0+\dots+a_nz^n$ is a polynomial of degree $n\geq 1$ (i. e. $a_n\not=0$), then 
$$|P(z)|\geq |z|^n\left(|a_n|-\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|z|}-\dots-\frac{|a_{0}|}{|z|^n}\right)\to+\infty$$
as $|z|\to +\infty$.

On the other hand, such property does not hold for an [entire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) (what you call improperly "infinite polynomial").

In fact note that $z_n=n\pi\to +\infty$, but
$$0=\sin(z_n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{z_n^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}.$$

Comment: Such a property, or anything else for that matter, doesn't hold for anything that is inexistent. Since an "infinite polynomial" doesn't exist in complex analysis, nothing applies to it.

Comment: @DonAntonio Is it better now?